# How do i call to reset the javascript CAPTCHA in my PHP file?

Tags: javascript, html, captcha

i'am using https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/image-puzzle-slider-captcha/ for a form, i need to make sure the fields are correct before it submits. Right now it just get stuck (the puzzle) if i press the button submit when the field{s} have not been filled.

If all the fields are ok, it submits fine.

```
<h2>Contact Form</h2>
            <form id="contact-form" action="" method="post">
            <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="website" name="website"/>

                <label class="name">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name:" data-constraints="@Required @JustLetters" />
                    <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
                    <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid name.</span>
                </label>
                <label class="email">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail:" data-constraints="@Required @Email" />
                    <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
                    <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid email.</span>
                </label>
                <label class="phone">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone:" data-constraints="@Required @JustNumbers"/>
                    <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
                    <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid phone.</span>
                </label>
                <label class="message">
                    <textarea placeholder="Message:" data-constraints='@Required @Length(min=20,max=999999)'></textarea>
                    <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
                    <span class="error-message">*The message is too short.</span>
                </label>
                <br>


   <script>
    $('#captcha').sliderCaptcha({
        repeatIcon: 'fa fa-redo',
        onSuccess: function () {
            //if form fields are OK submit.
            document.getElementById('submit').click();

            //if not ok, reset the slider.
        }
    });
</script>
```

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/image-puzzle-slider-captcha/disk/longbow.slidercaptcha.js

This file has a reset option but i don't know how to do it and do that in script above.